# android Fb Like Button via undefined

Tags: android, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am using facebook SDK 4.14.1. After clicking on like button, it redirects me to Like page. It says "via undefined" instead of my application name.
What I did wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to add Facebook Application Name in the manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
            android:value="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: yes, already changed. Fined the meta name from fb source codes

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution.
Should call:

```
FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
FacebookSdk.setApplicationName("App Name");
```